# Run psql in pgAdmin RDS database for gathering information?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-rds, psql, pgadmin

I have to run a SQL script file for gathering the performance and configuration information of RDS database.. can this be done in pg admin??

I also need to execute the same in psql against the RDS instance like:

```
 psql -h rdsendpointname.rds.amazonaws.com -U masteruser -f gather.sql > out.txt
```

- If I run the script in pgadmin query area.. it gives me errors, like:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 4: \pset tuples_only
        ^
SQL state: 42**
Character: 85
```

or

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 5: \echo '\\t'
        ^
SQL state: 42**
Character: 101
```

Comment: "my database server is connected there."  What do you mean?  You can connect to the database with any client you want to.  Why not just use psql?

Comment: @jjanes I meant that I can access my database in pgadmin. Now I need to run the script there but how? If I run it in the query section it gives me errors..